# libimagequant.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, importerror, manjaro

When importing matplotlib, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adama/Code/MachineLearning/HW6/problem1.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/home/adama/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 94, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: libimagequant.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried removing and reinstalling both matplotlib and libimagequant through both my OS (Manjaro) package manager and pip.  I have also tried editing my ld.so.conf file and running ldconfig, this is the current contents of the file:

```
# Dynamic linker/loader configuration.
# See ld.so(8) and ldconfig(8) for details.

include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib
include /usr/local/lib
include /usr/.local/lib
```

I also tried installing TA-lib, none of these did anything.  I think the problem originated because I using pip --break-system-packages.  I am considering deleting python and all packages, but I would really rather not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file `/lib/libimagequant.so.0.4` to `libimagequant.so.0`.

I had the same problem opening a tool but after renaming the file it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it looks like it was due to some conflict between pillow package and libimagequant in symlinks naming after ArchLinux upgrade of package `libimagequant`.

See : https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/80209?project=1&string=libimagequant

So depending on your Pillow version, you may encounter this issue.
Upgrading pillow to 10.2.0 solved the issue for me : `pip install pillow --upgrade`